# Show the full path to the file

Tags: mode-line

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1.

Suppose I open file **D:/temp/test/myfile.txt**.
But in the in the mode line show only file name (**myfile.txt**).

But I need to show FULL path to file: 
**D:/temp/test/myfile.txt**

This path can show on mode line OR in the frame title.
How I can do this?

Answer (score 7):

The variable `buffer-file-name` contains an absolute path of the file you are visiting.

To use in frame title:

```
    (setq frame-title-format
          '("" invocation-name ": "
            (:eval
             (if buffer-file-name
                 (abbreviate-file-name buffer-file-name)
               "%b"))))
```

To use it in the mode-line you can do the same, but for `mode-line-format` variable. If you need more help see `C-h v mode-line-format`

You can also use `%f`, like `(setq-default frame-title-format "%b (%f)")`

For a more thorough explanation see [here](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2011/01/setting-frame-title.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903426/display-path-of-file-in-status-bar)

Comment: +1 for mentioning `C-h v mode-line-format`. I would only add that that same docstring explains the meaning of identifiers like `%b`, `%f`, and many more, which apply to both `mode-line-format` and `frame-title-format`. From `C-h v frame-title-format`: *This variable has the same structure as ‘mode-line-format’, except that the %c, %C, and %l constructs are ignored.  It is used only on frames for which no explicit name has been set (see ‘modify-frame-parameters’)*.

Answer (score 1):

To show the current file path in the minibuffer you can do this:

```
(setq-default mode-line-buffer-identification
              (list 'buffer-file-name
                    (propertized-buffer-identification "%12f")
                    (propertized-buffer-identification "%12b")))
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing!!  This should be the official answer b/c it actually answers the question, rather than answering another question and redirecting to dense documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Did as follows:

Began installing `xdotool` package via `apt install xdotool`.

Then ran it via `xdotool getactivewindow getwindowgeometry` to get desired destination position, which gave me following output:

```
Window 69206023
  Position: 2201,251 (screen: 0)
  Geometry: 774x568
```

Entered it in a script, as:

```
#!/bin/bash
xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 2201 251 windowsize 774 568
```

Finally copied into `/usr/bin/moveright` and binded it on desired keystroke.