# Mode-line Directory Path Display

Tags: mode-line, path

Was seeking here a way to show in `mode-line` the full path of directory, as the answered question bellow:

[How can I show the full path to the current file in the mode-line for Spacemacs (Spaceline)?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36857/how-can-i-show-the-full-path-to-the-current-file-in-the-mode-line-for-spacemacs)

But it doesn't works in `Emacs 26.3`, maybe only in Spacemacs.

Although already made some research, couldn't find a way to do it propperly, despite tried several codes found around the web,.

Comment: I guess it is a duplicate of [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33388/how-show-full-path-to-file). Please, take a look at the answer proposed there.

Comment: Already checked it, have several deprecated items, as least at Emacs 26.3.